# Magento admin route extension resulting in 404

Tags: magento

I am currently involved in learning and developing for magento and i got stuff working for the frontend, but now im currently trying to get stuff working for the backend and im facing a challenge. According to the docs and to google, it should be simple, but im still getting the 404s.

I have created a standard filestructure, which looks like this:

```
app
  code
    local
      Mediafunction
        Csvengine
          Block
          controllers
            Adminhtml  
              IndexController.php
          etc
            config.xml
          Helper
            Data.php
          Model
          sql
```

I have in the config.xml added some stuff to get a link to the module shown in the menu, which actually works, but when im clicking the link (which resolves to /admin/csvengine/index/key/foobar, like it should), im just getting a 404.

I have tried various things, but i kept coming back to:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Mediafunction_Csvengine before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mediafunction_Csvengine_Adminhtml</Mediafunction_Csvengine>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

which does not currently work (the 404). My IndexController.php is extremely simple and its only contents is:

```
<?php
class Mediafunction_Csvengine_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Changing the name of the class have no effect either, and im really clueless about what im doing wrong. How can i get this working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two simple issues to fix :-)

First: capitalization. Every module file and directory (besides `controllers`, `etc/*`, `data/*`, and `sql/*` must be capitalized for case-sensitive filesystems. The reason for this is a combination of both direct implementation and of the way in which `Varien_Autoload` finds class definitions based on class names (the former applies to action controller classes though). This simply means that your module should be Csvengine rather than csvengine, and you must implement this in file names as well as in the module declaration node `modules/Mediafunction_Csvengine`.

Second: Your adminhtml controller approach is almost correct. Based on your classname, you would need to have a folder under `controllers` named `Adminhtml`. You also need to update the value at `admin/routers/adminhtml/args/modules/Mediafunction_csvengine` to be `Mediafunction_Csvengine`, as this will be used along with the module's codepool to find your action controller directory. See `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard::collectRoutes()` for the config-to-directory logic.

---

**EDIT**:

I neglected to point out the issue with your route (admin/csvengine/index) and your controller filename. In standard route-to-controller mapping, Magento URLs have five areas:

```
http://site.com/thisisparttwo/thisispartthree/thisispartfour/foo/1/bar/2/
Base URL       |front name   |controller path|method        | params...
```

Your controller path points to a CsvengineController class under the admin frontname. You've configured a controllers directory (with my changes) to be at `Mediafunction/Csvengine/controllers/Adminhtml/`, so in there you will need a CsvengineController.php which contains a class named `Mediafunction_Csvengine_Adminhtml_CsvengineController`

One other note, in general: Magento's admin ACL works through the `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::_isallowed()` method - without reimplementing this in your controller, access to the route is unrestricted for all admin users.

Comment: I have updated my post to reflect the changes i have made based on your post, i am however still faced with a 404 when i try to access /admin/csvengine/

Comment: Edited response to include path to controller mapping

Comment: Added additional note regarding ACL.